# Escaped single character introducer instead of actual character

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

For some reason \u009a is being sent to the xmlhttp.responseText and not \u0161, and I'm not sure why. I want š to be displayed in the textbox, but, instead, the single character introducer is being sent instead. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Main page code:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
         var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=a.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").value=a.second;
         document.getElementById("textbox3").value=a.third;
         document.getElementById("textbox4").value=a.fourth;
         document.getElementById("textbox5").value=a.fifth;
         document.getElementById("textbox6").value=a.sixth;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

loadTextBox.php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---Placeholder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
$textboxValue3 = $queryResult[2];
$textboxValue4 = $queryResult[3];
$textboxValue5 = $queryResult[4];
$textboxValue6 = $queryResult[5];
echo json_encode(array('first'=>utf8_encode($textboxValue),'second'=>
utf8_encode($textboxValue2),'third'=>utf8_encode($textboxValue3),'fourth'=>
utf8_encode($textboxValue4),'fifth'=>utf8_encode($textboxValue5),'sixth'=>
utf8_encode($textboxValue6)));
?>
```

Comment: Why have you posted both your JavaScript code and your PHP code? Surely you should have had no trouble determining which one has the bug?

Comment: Actually, I have no clue which one contains the bug. I am not an expert at web development.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert at Web development to type `http://....../loadTextBox.php?id=4` in Web browser's address bar and see whether the server is giving you the output you expect.

Comment: I have already done that. Doing that outputs the same thing my alert box outputs in the code above. For the data in question it shows \u009a not \u0161 like I would expect, and š is not being displayed. I don't know if this problem pertains to the main page or the loadTextBox.php page.

Comment: If `loadTextBox.php` is giving you `\u0161` when you expect `\u009a`, then the problem is in `loadTextBox.php`, so it's a PHP problem (or a MySQL problem).

Comment: Thank you I did not know that it meant the problem is in loadTextBox.php. Any idea what the problem might be? This problem has been bugging me for awhile now.

Comment: It's possible that you're double encoding your string, which causes unexpected results. Just make sure everything (the database content, the PHP script and strings, and the client-side page and script) is UTF8 and you're good to go. No need to use `utf8_encode()`.

Comment: Adding in the line $mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); inside loadTextBox.php after connecting to the DB and before the SQL query and removing the lines with utf8_encode fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding in the line $mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); inside loadTextBox.php after connecting to the DB and before the SQL query and removing the lines with utf8_encode fixed it.